# Using tail recursion to duplicate items on a list

Tags: list, prolog, tail-recursion, accumulator

I have a homework problem that asks us to write a predicate that creates a duplicate of every item on a list, first using linear recursion and then using tail recursion. We can't use built-in predicates.

I could solve it using linear recursion, but I'm having a bit of trouble with the tail recursion.

This is what I tried:

```
dup_elem_tail([], Res, Res).
dup_elem_tail([P | R], Lst2, Aux) :- dup_elems_tail(R, Lst2, [P, P | Aux]).
```

If the input is `dup_elem_tail([a, b, c], L)`. The output should be `L = [a, a, b, b, c, c]`. Instead, I got `[c, c, b, b, a, a]`.

Now, I know where my mistake is. In

```
dup_elem_tail([P | R], Lst2, Aux) :- dup_elems_tail(R, Lst2, [P, P | Aux]).
```

I am 'putting' the two Ps on the left side of the list, when I should be putting them in the right side. However, I am not finding a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an accumulator for this task. Simply construct the output list in the *head*:

```
dup_elems_tail([], []).
dup_elems_tail([P| Ps], [P, P | DPs]) :-
    dup_elems_tail(Ps, DPs).
```

Sample call:

```
| ?- dup_elems_tail([a, b, c], L).                                        

L = [a,a,b,b,c,c]
yes
```